# Allure Framework: how to validate xml, generated by my framework

Tags: xml, reporting-services, allure

I want to integrate my own test framework with Allure. 
But I need DTD to validate XML. Does somebody have a DTD file?

Has anybody already done it ?

Comment: Could you please explain more clearly what are you want? You can use XSD schema https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/blob/master/allure-model/src/main/resources/allure.xsd to validate xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use XSD schema https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/blob/master/allure-model/src/main/resources/allure.xsd to validate xml